# Get flow name from subflow

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

For the intended use of a library, I need to log the calling flow name from the called subflow that is who handles the logging. Is it possible to retrieve the name of a calling flow from a subflow?

I tried with flow.name , but it shows the name of the current flow/subflow.

Answer (score 0):

No, the caller flow name is not available. As an alternative you could save the flow name of the caller to a variable before using a flow reference.